# Insert message only once after keypress()

Tags: jquery, if-statement, insert

I wrote a simple function:

```
if ( some "charCode" is entered into <input> ) {
// display warning message
}
```

Problem is that if you enter the forbidden charCode repeatedly, the message gets inserted repeatedly too. I need it to be displayed **only once**, so I nested another "if":

```
  if ( some "charCode" is entered into <input> ) {
                  if (warning does not exist in the DOM) {
                     // insert the message
              } else {
                    //remove message and re-insert
          }
    }
```

Here is the code which is failing:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $('input').keypress(function (key) {
        var Warning = '<div class="exerciseWarning"><p>Warning msg</p></div>';
        if (key.charCode === 46 || key.charCode === 44) {
            if (Warning.length !== 0) {
                $('input').after(Warning);
                return false;

            } else {
                Warning.remove();
                $('input').after(Warning);
            }
        }
    }); // end of keypress()

    //last bracket
});
```

And the fiddle here --> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andreyka88/bcE7A/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking length of a string literal `Warning` that will never be 0. Instead you can check whether the next sibling of the current input element is a `exerciseWarning` element as shown below

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var Warning = '<div class="exerciseWarning"><p>Warning msg</p></div>';
    $('input').keypress(function (key) {
        if (key.charCode === 46 || key.charCode === 44) {
            var $this = $(this);
            if (!$this.next().is('.exerciseWarning')) {
                $('input').after(Warning);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }); // end of keypress()

    //last bracket
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gGZL6/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('input').keypress(function (key) {
            var Warning = '<div class="exerciseWarning"><p>Warning msg</p></div>';
            if (key.charCode === 46 || key.charCode === 44) {
                if ($('.exerciseWarning').length <= 0) {
                    $('input').after(Warning);
                    return false;

                } else {
                   // $('.exerciseWarning').remove();
                    //$('input').after(Warning);
                }
            }
        }); // end of keypress()

        //last bracket
    });

    // var stupidPunctuation = ['.',':'] ;
```